# Multivariable calculus: strict local minimum of $f(x,y) = y^2 - 3x^2y+2x^4$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, maxima-minima

Task Let $p:=(0,0)$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$f(x, y):=y^{2}-3 x^{2} y+2 x^{4}$$
Show:

a) For every $a=\left(a_{1}, a_{2}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \backslash\{(0,0)\}$, the function $g_{a}: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$g_{a}(t):=f(p+t a)$$
has a strict local minimum at $t=0$.

b) $f$ has no local minimum at $p$.
Hint: Consider $f$ along the curve $\gamma: t \mapsto\left(t, \sqrt{2} t^{2}\right)$ passing through $p$.

My solution:
a) We have
$$g_{a}(t)=f(p+ta)=f((0,0)+t\cdot(a_1,a_2))=f(ta_1,ta_2)=t^2a_2^2-3t^3a_1^2a_2+2t^4a_1^4$$
$$g_a'(t)=2ta_2^2-9t^2a_1^2a_2+8t^3a_1^4$$

Necessary condition:

$g_a'(t)=0$,
$0=2ta_2^2-9t^2a_1^2a_2+8t^3a_1^4$,
$0=t(2a_2^2-9ta_1^2a_2+8t^2a_1^4)$

Case 1

$t_1=0$

Case 2

$$\begin{aligned}
2a_2^2-9ta_1^2a_2+8t^2a_1^4 &= \frac{2a_2^2}{8a_1^4}-\frac{9a_1^2a_2}{8a_1^4}t+t^2 \\
&= \frac{a_2^2}{4a_1^4}-\frac{9a_2}{8a_1^2}t+t^2, \\
t_{2,3} &= \frac{9a_2}{16a_1^2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{81a_2^2}{256a_1^4}-\frac{64a_2^2}{256a_1^4}} \\
&= \frac{9a_2}{16a_1^2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{17}a_2}{16a_1^2}, \\
t_2 &= \frac{a_2(9+\sqrt{17})}{16a_1^2}, \\
t_3 &= \frac{a_2(9-\sqrt{17})}{16a_1^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Sufficient condition
$$g_a''(t)=2a_2^2-18a_1^2a_2t+24t^2a_1^4$$
Then,
$$g_a''(t_1)=2a_2^2>0$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}0<t^2a_2^2-3t^3a_1^2a_2+2t^4a_1^4,\\ 
0<t^2(ta_1^2-a_2)(2ta_1^2-a_2)\end{aligned}(*)$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{True statement}$$
$$\Rightarrow t_1=0 \text{ is a strict local minimum}$$

**Problems:**

I'm struggeling with my approach of (*). And for b) I don't really have an idea but I substituted $(t,\sqrt{2}t^2)$ into $f$ and get $f(t,\sqrt{2}t^2) = t^4(\sqrt{16}-\sqrt{18})< 0$.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For b): I think you mean for the last inequality to be t^4 (√16 - √18) ≤ 0. Now if f had a local minimum at p, what would that minimum value be?

Comment: @DanAsimov  The derivative of $f(t,\sqrt{2}t^2) = 4(\sqrt{16}-\sqrt{18})t^3$, so if $f$ would have a local minimum at p it would be $t = 0$

Comment: How can $f(0,0)=0$ be less than or equal to all nearby values if there are points arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ where $f$ is negative?

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that $g_a =f(p + ta)$ as a local minimum for $t = 0$

Once you know that $g_a'(t)$ cancels out at $t = 0$ there is no point in wasting your time trying to find the other roots of $g_a'$. Indeed you are only interested in proving that there is a minimum at $t = 0. Solving

$$2a_2^2-9ta_1^2a_2+8t^2a_1^4 = 0$$ is just a waste of time. Now that you know that $t = 0$ cancels out $g'_a$ consider the sign of the second derivative  **at $t = 0$ only !** Your calculations show that the second derivative is positive at $t = 0$ so we have a local minimum for $g_a$ at $t = 0.$

This solves $a)$

---

For $b)$ use the hint and consider $$f(t,\sqrt 2 t^2) = 2t^4 -3t^2 \sqrt 2 t^2 + 2 t^4 = t^4(4-3 \sqrt 2)$$
which is $\leq 0$ for all values of $t$.

It follows that the function $f$ has no local minima at $p$.